# Sort multiple arrays based on single array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have multiple arrays. Lets take three for example: first name, last name, and age:

```
var first_name = ['Bob', 'Bob', 'Joe', 'Zeek', 'Ryan',];
var last_name = ['Mallard', 'Li', 'Rose', 'Ay', 'Li'];
var age = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

- So Bob Mallar is 1 year old.
- Bob Li is 2.
- Joe Rose is 3.
- Zeek Ay is 4.
- Ryan Li is 5.

I want to sort last_name, and based on that: first_name and age should get sorted respectively. So final result should be:

```
var first_name = ['Zeek', 'Bob', 'Ryan', 'Joe', 'Zeek'];
var last_name = ['Ay', 'Li', 'Li', 'Mallard', 'Rose'];
var age = [4, 2, 3, 1, 3];
```

I tried some mess, if you would like to see its here but it might confuse you as I was trying to use native sort: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/97b4177950faa6f4c2d1

This is just research, i know for application i would actually want to use an array of objects. Can even turn these into an array of objects then sort, then re-create the arrays. But I was just doing this for research.

Comment: Why don't you use an array of objects?

Comment: I suggest you change the data structure to one array with person objects. That will make it a whole lot easier

Comment: Very true, this was just research for fun. I'll note that in topic.

Comment: If you insist on using arrays, take a snapshot of the indexes before and after you sort one of the arrays, then you'd know how to sort the rest as well

Comment: Thanks @Johan ! Ill do that!